# Where does the value of 'Last changed on/by' is stored for any element in 'se11' (Inside attributes tab)

Tags: sap-data-dictionary

[image: Underlined the value i need to find]

I want to find out 'last changed on/by' for a large number of elements going in 'se11' and checking it's attribute value .
So instead of copying each elements name and checking it's attribute for the same value, is there any table or database in which i can get the values for multiple entries at once?
Picture is attached in the question for the reference.

Comment: ...what ever happened to screen shot software...???

Answer (score 4):

With the cursor placed in the field you're interested in, press F1, then select the technical info. This will show you the table name or - as in this case - a structure named `RSDXX`, which is not what you're looking for - but it is the fastest way in some cases.

Alternatively, start transaction `ST05`, enable the SQL trace and navigate to the display in a separate window. Then stop the trace and examine it - you will find a list of all tables accessed for the process. Very near the top of the trace list, you will find a table named `DD02L` which is the one you're looking for in this case.

Comment: Thank you. Solved my query for table names.. other elements like 'data type' , 'table type' etc. are not there in DD02L, still need to be found out.. anyway thank you so much, helped a lot.